# How to create a list of list after joining 2 lists in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have 2 list and I am trying to join them and expected is a list of lists. 
Can you please suggest on the same?
I have tried using + operator and append as well.

```
list_output_first = []
list_output_second = []
list_a = [1,2,[]]
list_b = ['a',['b', '']]

list_output_first = list_a + list_b 

list_output_first = list_a.append(list_b)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[1, 2, [], ['a', ['b', '']]]
```

**EXPECTED**

```
[[1, 2, []], ['a', ['b', '']]]
```

Comment: list_output_first = [list_a, list_b]

Answer (score 1):

You need to built a main list, that contains the 2 others:

```
list_output_first = [list_a, list_b]
```

Or built it empty, and add the 2 others:

```
list_output_first = []
list_output_first.append(list_a)
list_output_first.append(list_b)
```

---

**Reference** in both example solution up there, you pass the list itself, so if you modify `list_a` or `list_b` later, you'll the the changes in `list_output_first` too. If you want to have a copy of the lists inside `list_output_first` do

```
list_output_first = [list(list_a), list(list_b)] 
# and for the other: 
list_output_first.append(list(list_a))
```

---

The `+` operator for lists *sums* them together making one list with elements of each, you need an extra container where your put the both lists A list and not their values

Comment: Can you explain what is difference between using +, append and your approach.i.e. using [list_a, list_b]?

Comment: @TanayGupta add some text. You just need to know that doing with the 2 list concat them, you need an extra list to put them both

Answer (score 0):

just do:

```
list_output_first = [list_a, list_b]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this :

```
list_output_first = [list_a] + [list_b]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Just add two list by placing them in a list

```
list_a = [1,2,[]]
list_b = ['a',['b', '']]
print([list_a]+[list_b])
#[[1, 2, []], ['a', ['b', '']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be many ways, here I am sharing two ways that I find simple.
first way:- You can extend list_b into list_a and print list_a. If you want to store it in another list that You can create another list and store a copy of list in which you extended other list.

```
list_a = [1, 2, []]
list_b = ['a', ['b', '']]
list_a.extend(list_b)
list_c = list_a.copy()
print(list_c)
```

second way:- You can add both list and store it in an empty list.

```
list_a = [1, 2, []]
list_b = ['a', ['b', '']]
list_c = list_a + list_b
print(list_c)
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want list without backref connection with elements it is made from:

```
from copy import deepcopy
answer = [ item for item in (deepcopy(list_a), deepcopy(list_b)) ]
```